# How can I avoid multiple declaration of namespaces in different pages?

Tags: templates, jsf, namespaces

Well, imagine I got two different Facelets with identical `Namespaces`:

```
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:a="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui"
```

How can I create a base of `Namespaces`, which is included every time? Or even a template of `Namespaces`. So, If I will add a new Namespace, it is automatically included in all other Facelets (webpages).

Comment: I am concret asking about to extract the declaration in a template (`xhtml`) file or create a base of Namespaces, not as taglib/tagfile. If it is the same as pointed out in your answer, than it is a duplicate.

Comment: Question is perhaps not same, but answer is same: it's not possible. Best what you can get is IDE tooling.

Comment: So, If I want to add a new namespace in EVERY page, I need to edit EVERY page? Is that true?

Comment: Only when you need it in the XHTML file itself. Note that decent IDEs have also a "find-and-replace-in-all-files" facility, Eclipse has even a regex based one with preview.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. Thanks anyway. Should I delete my question? You can mark it as duplicate, anyway.

Comment: Hmm, I think I now see the ambiguity in your question. You absolutely don't need to (re)declare a XML namespace which isn't used anywhere in the current XML file. This is further not strictly related to JSF/Facelets.

Comment: And what is about `Namespaces` which are used in EVERY file? Can I sum up them in a `template.xhtml`?

Comment: Sorry, I'm now not understanding you anymore. Can you please tell in your own words what exactly you mean with "Namespaces"? Perhaps the ambiguity/misunderstanding is exactly there.

Comment: No need to sorry here. I am also a bit confused. Please look at my question, those in the codesnippet are ``Namespaces` for me. Is this wrong? I have in almost all files the same definition of those `Namespaces` and want to sum it up in a template.xhtml. Can I do this? Is this the wrong attempt?

Comment: Hm, that's answered in the proposed duplicate. I'm now not understanding anymore how the duplicate is different from your question.

Comment: Yes, you are totally right! I misunderstood the propoesed question.

Comment: Okay :) World is now well again.